# How to show recursive computation graphically?

Tags: graphics, algorithm

I am studying the book "Computer Science with Mathematica" from R. Maeder. The following piece of code solves the Knapsack Problem recursively:

```
size[object_] := object[[1]]
value[object_] := object[[2]]

total[knapsack_, vs_] := Plus @@ value /@ vs[[knapsack]] (* total value *) 
contents[knapsack_, vs_] := Plus @@ size /@ vs[[knapsack]] (* total size *) 

Knapsack[{}, s_Integer?NonNegative] := {} (* Case 1 *)

Knapsack[vs_List, s_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Module[{sn = size[Last[vs]], n = Length[vs], rest = Drop[vs, -1], k1,
    k2},
      k1 = Knapsack[rest, s] ;         (* 2a: without last object *) 
      If[s >= sn,
            k2 = Knapsack[vs, s - sn]; (* 2b: with one last object *) 
            k2 = Append[k2, n];
            If[total[k1, vs] >= total[k2, vs], k1, k2] (* 3: the maximum *)
     , 
      k1
     ]
  ]
```

The function is called as follows:

```
objects = {{3, 4}, {4, 5}, {7, 10}, {8, 11}, {9, 13}};
Knapsack[objects, 17]
```

**{3,4,7,8,9}** are the sizes of the objects and the corresponding values are **{4,5,10,11,13}**.
The capacity of the Knapsack is **17**.

The result is **{1,3,3}** which means the optimal solution consists of one object of type **1** ({3, 4}) and two objects of type **3** ({7, 10}).

The optimal value achieved with this solution is **24**:

```
total[%, objects]
```

In the book the recursive computation is also shown graphically by a function called KnapsackPlot in package CSM`KnapsackG (Page 159 and 160). Unfortunately I don't have access to this package.

```
KnapsackPlot[objects, 17]
```

[image: KnapsackPlot]

According to the description KnapsackPlot does the following:

Draw one node, labeled with the maximum reached. The two recursive calls that find k1 and k2 are connected by a line. The line corresponding to the larger value is draws in bold.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement KnapsackPlot to produce graphic like shown in the picture above?